# Fill set columns to pdf

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, page-setup

I am exporting a `.xlsm` sheet to PDF using Visual Basic (VBA).
I only want to export the columns `A:Z`.

I have tried this:

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws.PageSetup
            .PrintArea = "$A:$Z"
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = False
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .PaperSize = xlPaperA3
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        End With
    Next
```

```
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Diagram").Select
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=strFilename, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

But I get space on the right side like it has filled the whole page just hid the columns I didn't select...

Is it any way to fix this problem and make column `A:Z` fill the whole page?

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: But where in your code did you set "A:Z" range to be published? Did you manually select the columns in discussion?

Comment: My bad, forgot to paste that line in the post :/ (updated now) But I have done that, and the coloumns does not fill the width of the PDF...

Comment: `IgnorePrintAreas` should be `False` to consider PrintArea

Comment: Yes. ``IgnorePrintAreas`` -> ``False`` and editing the ``Zoom`` value till it fit worked :)